# How to check whether my network connection supports HTTP2, gRPC or WebSocket?

Tags: networking, webserver, https, benchmark, tcp-ip

My ISP/AS/NAT is problematic since I think it blocks some transfer-layer protocols.
I want to check whether my connection to my domain behind a CDN (e.g. cloudflare) supports HTTP/2, gRPC, QUIC or WebSocket etc.

How can I do this provided that I have ssh access to server?
Is there , like, a "HTTP analysis tool" for this?

The way I see it, I should run a HTTPS server on remote on port 443. Then run some "benchmarking" tool on local against the remote HTTPS server. But how can I enforce a transfer-layer protocol?

Sorry I don't have networking knowledge and I don't know the proper technical phrases for these. Bottom-line is **I want a tool like iperf3 to quantify the performance of different transfer-layer protocols in my connection which is behind a NAT/ISP/AS**.

Comment: I don't understand this question, it's comparing apples to pears: these protocols exist in different layers of the OSI stack. WebSocket lives "inside" HTTP, HTTP lives "inside" QUIC or TCP/IP. So *what are you trying to measure?*

Comment: @Panki Suppose webserver A is using HTTP1 and webserver B is using QUIC. I want to stress test my network in accessing these websites. As in, I want to find out how many packets were droped due to TLS handshake error or connection reset etc